# how to use 'brew' for install gcc on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, appium, homebrew, appium-android, linuxbrew

when i want to run `brew install gcc` on Ubuntu 18.04, i got an error:

```
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.
```

i want to install appium on Ubuntu VPS.
please help me to install appium or solve this problem.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkJYj.png)

Comment: Did you read that error? Why not run Homebrew with limited permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reinstall brew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

And then you can run:

```
brew install gcc
```